# Limit of groups

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

My question concerns the properties of special limits of groups. Let $G'$ and $G''$ be two small groups. Suppose that the following diagram in the category $\mathfrak{Grp}$ of small groups and morphisms between them exists.

$
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad G' \longrightarrow G' \cap G'' \longleftarrow G''
$

I would like to compute the limit of this diagram explicitly. What kind of operation between groups gives the limit?

Comment: What do you mean by a "small" group? Are they subgroup of a larger group, given that you take their intersection? And what do you call the "natural projection" to the intersection, too...?

Comment: I use the word "small" in the set-theory sense - i.e. the groups I work with are sets, and not proper classes. Since $G' \cap G'' \subseteq G'$, we can define a map $\pi:G'\longrightarrow G'\cap G''$ such that $\pi|_{G'\cap G''} = \text{id}_{G'\cap G''}$ and $\text{ker}(\pi ) = (G' \setminus (G'\cap G'')) \cup \{e\}$. Those are the maps I refer to when I write "natural projection".

Comment: That projection you talk about doesn't exist. Take $G' = (\mathbb{Z}, +)$, $G'' = (2 \mathbb{Z}, +) \subset G'$. There is no morphism $\pi : \mathbb{Z} \to G' \cap G'' = 2 \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\pi|_{2\mathbb{Z}} = \operatorname{id}_{2\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: I think the question was badly written. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you wanted to construct a pullback in category of groups. See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_%28category_theory%29). It is good exercise to check that set $G\times_H G' = \{ (x,x')\ |\ f(x) = g(x') \}$ with projections $(x,x')\mapsto x$, $(x,x')\mapsto x'$ is a pullback of the diagram $G\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} H \stackrel{g}{\leftarrow} G'$ with multiplication defined component-wise: $(x,x')\cdot (y,y') = (xy,x'y')$.